# C# SDK version 6.0.20 - (OAuthException - #190) Error validating access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-login

I am using Facebook C# SDK version 6.0.20 to authenticate the user.

It worked fine for me and I was able to get the user's first and last names. But when I tried at a later time, I am getting the access token, but `fbClient.Get(“me”)` is failing with the following error:

> (OAuthException – #190) Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.

Please help.

I run the following code when user is redirected back from the **auth dialog**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Params["code"] != null)
    {
      Facebook.FacebookClient fbClient = new Facebook.FacebookClient(GetAccessToken());

        dynamic me = fbClient.Get("me");

        string firstName = me.first_name;
        string lastName = me.last_name;
        string email = me.email;
        string userID = me.id;
        string gender = me.gender;
        string dob = me.birthday;
        string locale = me.locale;
        string mStatus = me.relationship_status;            
    }

}

private string GetAccessToken()
{
    if (HttpRuntime.Cache["access_token"] == null)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> args = GetOauthTokens(Request.Params["code"]);
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("access_token", args["access_token"], null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(args["expires"])), TimeSpan.Zero);
    }

    return HttpRuntime.Cache["access_token"].ToString();
}

private Dictionary<string, string> GetOauthTokens(string code)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    string clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string redirectUrl = "http://localhost:51215/TestFBWebSite/FacebookRedirect.aspx";
    string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?  client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_secret={2}&code={3}",
                    clientId, redirectUrl, clientSecret, code);

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string retVal = reader.ReadToEnd();

        foreach (string token in retVal.Split('&'))
        {
            tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
        }
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fbClient.Get("me") does work (without a preceding "/"), that's what we are using and it works correctly.

```
string redirectUrl = "http://localhost:51215/TestFBWebSite/FacebookRedirect.aspx";
```

I noticed this part - I had found that the integration does not work when using localhost (or 127.0.0.1), we resolved this by setting up a host record for "test.mydomain.com" to point to 127.0.0.1

We are encountering the #190 error as well very occasionally in our live environment.  It is strange, as the location that is generating the error should only ever be triggered once Facebook has just authenticated the user, so the auth token should not have expired already!
We are coding to handle this error (ie. don't authenticate the user onto our system), however so far the two possibilities that I can think of as causes of the problem are:

1. We are calling Facebook too quickly after getting the token - could be a possibility if there is a replication delay at Facebook passing the new Auth Token to all the relevant servers
2. General internal error at Facebook

I think it's probably option 1, however I've not found enough information to back it up yet

Comment: I moved my code to the live environment and it seems to work fine now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a syntax error at the begining.

```
dynamic me = fbClient.Get("/me");

        string firstName = me.first_name;
        string lastName = me.last_name;
        string email = me.email;
        string userID = me.id;
        string gender = me.gender;
        string dob = me.birthday;
        string locale = me.locale;
        string mStatus = me.relationship_status;
```

try this code use "\me" instead of "me"

Comment: both "\me" and "me" works fine when I moved my code to the live environment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your account will be blocked and appeared 190 error code If you send friend request more to the unknown person. So cancel the request and login again.